# Show two jQuery UI ToolTips at once

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-ui-tooltip

Using the [jQuery UI ToolTip plug-in](http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip), how can one show multiple ToolTips at once?

My reason for showing up to two ToolTips is because I have an informational message for a field and, potentially, an error message for the field.

The current HTML is as follows:

```
<li title="This is an informational ToolTip message">
  <input type="text" class="error" title="This is an error ToolTip message">
</li>
```

The current JavaScript:

```
$('body').tooltip({
  track: true
});
$('body').tooltip({
  items: '.error',
  position: {my: 'left bottom-15', at: 'left top', collision: 'flipfit'},
  track: true
});
```

The current problem is that when entering the `<li>`, the informational ToolTip displays properly, but when the mouse enters over the field itself, the informational ToolTip fades out and the error ToolTip alone is displayed. I need both to display at the same time.

Comment: This raises red flags for usability. Errors should be accessible, and they won't be in tooltips. Are you sure you want to go this route? If so, I'd use jQuery to append the second message in a single tooltip.

Comment: It's called a tooltip and not tooltips for a reason. If you still want to implement it, why not write a small plugin?

Comment: Why do you need 2 tooltips in the first place? Can you not put multiple tips/instructions in one tooltip?

Comment: I may agree that having two ToolTips at once is not ideal, though I think it works here (a user can hover over a red-marked error field to see details of the error whilst seeing the informational message too). *But that's not the question.*

Comment: Can you provide your current code on a fiddle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I force your question work. but it's so ugly. I am not recommend you do this. but give your idea.

the idea is using one tooltip open/close event to control other tooltips programmatically.

please see jsfiddle example ：[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3RyPg/)

```
   $('li').tooltip({
  track: true,
    open: function( event, ui ) {
      $('input').tooltip('open');
  },
    close: function( event, ui ) {
      $('input').tooltip('close');
  }
});
$('input').tooltip({
  items: '.error',
  position: {my: 'left bottom-15', at: 'left top', collision: 'flipfit'},
  track: true,
  open: function( event, ui ) {
      $('li').tooltip('open');
  },
    close: function( event, ui ) {
      $('li').tooltip('close');
  }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

If it were me... I'd just include the text from the first tooltip at the bottom of the contents of the error tooltip...

```
var i="this is INFO tooltip text"

Tooltip 1 = i

Tooltip 2 = "Error text" + i
```

Sorry, can't give you real code because I don't use jquery - just javascript, but should be simple enough anyways...

Answer (score -1):

You should have to apply preventDefault() into OnOver listener of li element.